# Can't view any 'dependencies' inside zipkin UI dependencies tab

Tags: spring-boot, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I do have several services interacting with each other, and all of them, sending traces to openzipkin ( https://github.com/openzipkin/docker-zipkin ).

While i can see the system behaviour in detail , looks like the 'dependencies' tab does not display anything at all.

The trace i check has 6 services, 21 spans and 43 spans, and i believe something should appear.

I'm using latest ( 1.40.1 ) docker-zipkin, with cassandra as storage, and 
just connecting to the cassandra instance, can see there's no entry in the dependencies 'table'. why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here with the docker images using Cassandra (1.40.1, 1.40.2, 1.1.4).

This is a problem specific to using Cassandra as the storage tier.  Mysql and the in-memory storage generate the dependency graph on-demand as expected.

There are references to the following project to generate the Cassandra graph data for the UI to display.

- https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-dependencies-spark

This looks to be superseded by ongoing work mentioned here

- https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-dependencies-spark/issues/22

Answer (score 1):

> If storage type is other than inline storage, for zipkin dependencies graph you have to start separate cron job/scheduler which reads the storage database and builds the graph. Because zipkin dependencies is separate spark job .
>   For reference : https://github.com/openzipkin/docker-zipkin-dependencies
>
> I have used zipkin with elastic search as storage type. I will share the steps for setting up the zipkin dependencies with elastic search and cron job for the same:

```
1.cd ~/
2. curl -sSL https://zipkin.io/quickstart.sh | bash -s io.zipkin.dependencies:zipkin-dependencies:LATEST zipkin-dependencies.jar
3. touch  cron.sh or vi cron.sh  
4. paste this content  : 
STORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch ES_HOSTS=https:172.0.0.1:9200 ES_HTTP_LOGGING=BASIC ES_NODES_WAN_ONLY=true java -jar zipkin-dependencies.jar
5.chmode a+x cron.sh //make file executable
6.crontab -e   
window will open paste  below content 
0 * * * * cd && ./cron.sh //every one hour it will start the cron job if you need every 5 minutes change the commmand to '*/5 * * * * cd && ./cron.sh'
7. to check cron job is schedule run commant crontab -l
```

> Other solution is to start a separate service and run the cron job
>   using docker
>
> Steps to get the latest zipkin-dependencies jar try running given
>   command on teminal

```
cd /zipkindependencies // where your Dockerfile is available
curl -sSL https://zipkin.io/quickstart.sh | bash -s io.zipkin.dependencies:zipkin-dependencies:LATEST
```

> you will get jar file at above mention directory
>
> Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
ENV STORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch
ENV ES_HOSTS=http://172.0.0.1:9200
ENV ES_NODES_WAN_ONLY=true
ADD crontab.txt /crontab.txt
ADD script.sh /script.sh
COPY entry.sh /entry.sh
COPY zipkin-dependencies.jar  /
RUN chmod a+x /script.sh /entry.sh
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /crontab.txt
CMD ["/entry.sh"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

> entry.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# start cron
/usr/sbin/crond -f -l 8
```

> script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /zipkin-dependencies.jar
```

> crontab.txt

```
0 * * * * /script.sh >> /var/log/script.log
```